# urhosharpの初期化と終了処理

Tags: ios, c#, urhosharp, xamarin

iOSで、UrhoSharpを組み込んだアプリを作成しようとしています。

「画面A」　→　「画面B」に遷移した際に、「画面B」上に、UrhoSharpで3Dを表示、
といった実装です。

ただ、UrhoSharpの初期化(Urho.Applicationの構築)と、終了処理(UrhoApp.ErrorExit)を行うと、画面Bに２回目以降遷移すると、表示されなくなります。

正しい初期化/終了処理は、どのような手順なのか？を教えていただけないでしょうか？

※対策として、アプリ起動時に初期化を行い、以降は終了処理を行わないという方法を試すと、２回目以降も表示されるようにはなるのですが、カメラ画像を表示する「画面C」で例外が発生する状況です。

※検証バージョンは、UrhoSharp 1.0.360以前です。

Comment: UrhoSharp for Xamarin.Formsが配信されたので、それでも検証しましたが、同様でした。
iOSでは、終了処理が機能していない、という情報があります。
中の人の調査/実装待ちという状態になっています。